# ¿Como puedo hacer que los oyentes de una etiqueta funcionen cuando esta no es opaca?

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo un `JLabel` el cual esta sin opacidad, tiene un oyente que detecta cuando entra el cursor, y al entrar se muestra una imagen, al salir, la imagen se hace invisible, el problema es que cuando un componente no es opaco, sus oyentes no funcionan si no hay nada visible dentro de este, se me ocurrió que en vez de hacer que no tenga opacidad, ponerle que si la tenga, pero de fondo use un color transparente, el problema es que java-swing no soporta muy bien la transparencia(RGBA) o yo no se implementarla.

Como referencia:

La barra blanca es el `JLabel` cuando es opaco. Como se ve, el cursor esta dentro del `JLabel`, por lo tanto se muestra la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui el `JLabel` no es opaco, por lo que no se ve, pero esta ahi. El cursor esta dentro del `JLabel,` pero el oyente no detecta que este ahi y en consecuencia no se ve la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y asi es como quiero que funcione:

El `JLabel` no tiene opacidad y al pasar el cursor por encima aparecería la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto el codigo del `JLabel`:

```java
final JLabel OCULTAR = new JLabel();
OCULTAR.setBounds(BARRA.getX() + 2, BARRA.getHeight() - 1, 509, 15);
OCULTAR.setHorizontalAlignment(0);
OCULTAR.setOpaque(false);
CONTENEDOR.add(OCULTAR);

OCULTAR.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {


           @Override
           public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {

               OCULTAR.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imagen.png));

           }

           @Override
           public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {

               OCULTAR.setIcon(null);

           }

       });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No escuches cuando el apuntador entre a la etiqueta, sino escucha la posición del apuntador en el [*Glass Pane*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html#glasspane) del JFrame y verifica si se encuentra dentro de los límites de la etiqueta:

```
public class Ejemplo extends JFrame{
   
   JLabel lbl = new JLabel("...");
   
   public Ejemplo() {
      super();
      this.setLayout(null);
      this.setBounds(100, 100, 640, 480);
      
      this.getGlassPane().setVisible(true);
      this.getGlassPane().addMouseMotionListener( new MouseMotionListener(){
         @Override
         public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){
            // Cuando el apuntador esta sobre la etiqueta ...
            if( lbl.getBounds().contains(e.getPoint()) )
               lbl.setText("=>"+e.getPoint().toString());
         }

         @Override
         public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){}

      });
      
      lbl.setBounds(0,0,640,30);
      lbl.setOpaque(false);
      this.add(lbl);
   }
   
   public static void main(String[] args){
      new Ejemplo().setVisible(true);
   }
}
```